# Owl Carousel and Wordpress Integration Via WP_Enqueue

Tags: functions, jquery

I'd like to use this particular carousel and can't seem to figure out how to initialize it in Wordpress. I stumbled across a similar ([How to integrate owl carousel into theme without using a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180347/how-to-integrate-owl-carousel-into-theme-without-using-a-plugin)) post, but the answers provided did not solve my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code in my functions.php file (top two enqueues are not related):

```
function loadup_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respondjs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/respond.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scriptjs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-def', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadup_scripts' );
```

Here's my HTML/Bootstrap markup on front-page.php:

```
    <div class="container owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-supplies.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-storage.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-security.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-boxes.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-computer-controlled-03.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-flexible-terms-05.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-insurance-06.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-shipping.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-units.svg"/></div>                         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to move the .owl-carousel and .owl-theme classes to inner divs, however this did not help.

I've initialized the script before the closing body tag with some php found in that other post:

```
    <?php if(is_page('front-page.php')): ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
        }); 
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Console errors that I do not understand.

[image: jquery console errors]

Comment: first, I would make sure that your javascript is working. Have you tried a simple alert('working') in your jquery  where you are initializing the owl? It can be a major pain in the but to get this working depending on the other scripts you have going. I don't see any script call above for your jquery. I am assuming that it's there and you just didn't list it. Next, have you clicked all the links for the scripts in the source? Do they go to the right pages? Make sure all your url's are good for the scripts you are enqueueing. Finally, disable all other plugins to see if that does anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. jQuery is installed, but I'm receiving errors. I'm new to jQuery so not sure what they mean.

Comment: It looks like the issue may be your theme, the jQuery errors reference `googleapis.com` as the source of the jQuery library, default WordPress loads a local copy of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is very important to enqueue your scripts in the proper order otherwise it will not work out.
And remember always enqueue your custom script at the very end of the queue.

You have not included last two parameters of the wp_enqueue_script() function as well. use true if you want to load it in the footer of the document and false otherwise.

```
 function loadup_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respondjs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/respond.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scriptjs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-def', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadup_scripts' );
```

and you may use following code instead:

```
    <div class="container owl-carousel owl-theme">

            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-supplies.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-storage.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-security.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-boxes.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-computer-controlled-03.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-flexible-terms-05.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-insurance-06.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-shipping.svg"/></div>
            <div><img class="caro-item" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/slider-units.svg"/></div>                         

</div>
```

Don't forget to use browser's console feature to figure out JavaScript errors. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help maverick. The carousel still doesn't work. I've updated the post with an image of some jQuery errors via the browser console. Not sure what they mean.

Comment: The order you enqueue scripts shouldn't matter, the dependencies argument controls order. If the order you enqueue causes something to not work, you are not using dependencies correctly.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't matter if you are not overriding anything with your script.
I was talking about overriding, and in this it surely matters.
Thanks for the comment.